# Simple angular repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm new to js/html/css etc., and trying to teach myself angular, but I'm stuck on something that seems simple.

When I load the page described below, I get the title and a one item list containing the text that I want angular to replace "{{e.someKey}}".  What I'm looking for is two bullets - someValue1 and someValue2.

In index.html:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="myfirstapp">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>my first app</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/app.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css">
  <script src="lib/angular/angular.js"></script>
  <script src="js/app.js"></script>
  <script src="js/controllers.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>My First App</h1>
  <div ng-controller="MyFirstAppController">
    <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="e in elementArray">
        <p>{{e.someKey}}</p>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

The controller looks like this:

```
function MyFirstAppController($scope) {
    $scope.elementArray = [
        { someKey : 'someValue1', someOtherKey : 'someOtherValue1' },
        { someKey : 'someValue2', someOtherKey : 'someOtherValue2' }
    ];
}
```

I've tried loads of syntax tweaks to this, but I must be missing something more fundamental.  Any ideas much appreciated!

Comment: i suggest fiddle-ing it, like so... http://jsfiddle.net/9FxrT/; what's in app.js?

Comment: thanks.  will check that out.  app.js is empty.  just `use 'strict'`;

Comment: @adam77 - thanks.  that's a very cool tool.  so far it's demonstrating the problem, but I'm still clueless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply change it to:

```
<html lang="en" ng-app>
```

Here's a working version of the JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/EgPYA/

Comment: OP has `ng-app` specified with `myfirstapp` which means that Angular is looking for controllers within the `myfirstapp` module which he hasn't defined in the JS. Though I could have suggested him/her to use `angular.module('myfirstapp').controller('MyFirstAppController', function($scope) { CODE_HERE });` this would have probably confused the OP. Therefore, the simplest way to fix his/her problem is to remove the value specified in `ng-app`.

Comment: wow, that's it!  thanks very much!  googling this a little, i don't see why that causes it to fail silently.  does that app name cause it to go looking for something that's not there?

Comment: The ng-app name, if specified limits the scope of where Angular looks for your code (controllers, directives, etc). I guess it's a way to not pollute the global name space in JS.

Comment: I doesn't really 'fail silently'. I would recommend running the console while you are trying to debug your application. Especially if you are new to development it will not only help you pin point errors, but also better understand DOM fundamentals.